# Qt: active chats control

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to figure out what component that would be best to use for a active chats control.

I've attached an image with the layout that I'm aiming for.

[image]

Basically I want to add an icon to the left of each conversation, depending if the conversation is active or not. The middle column is the name of the conversation and the last column is an indicator if there are new messages for this conversation. However, if the row is selected the indicator should switch out to a close conversations button.

I've through about using:
- Listview, however this would not give me multiple columns?
- Treeview
- Tableview - this might be the best solution. However in unsure of how to add icons and buttons to different cells

Which one would be my best bet here?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on API you want to achieve. Most importantly, who will be the close handler/listener:

1. You can go for a table view with three different delegates. This way the caller is responsible to set up the close event.
2. Or you can make it list view, which internally creates listView/GridView. This way the conversation itself would be the listener to the close event.

It's up to you to decide which of these (there may be more) is more suitable to your existing codebase

Comment: Any ideas if there is an example out there somewhere that i could start with? Really feel lost at this point

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple delegate to implement (and you work in QML), you can really use a `ListView` to get the job done.

Here is a self-contained prototype of your layout. Change `Rectangle` by `Image`. You see that color vary accordingly as the model give an odd or even number. You can in the same way change  the `Component` to load, the `source` of an `Image`, whatever you can imagine.

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 200

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 3


        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: rect
            width: parent.width
            height: 60
            property bool selected: false
            color: selected ? "darkblue" : "transparent"

            Rectangle {
                id: bubbleIcon
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                width: 40
                height: 40
                color: "lightblue"
            }

            Text {
                id: chatName
                anchors.left: bubbleIcon.right
                anchors.leftMargin: 10
                height: parent.height
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                text: "chat" + modelData
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: notificationIcon
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                width: 40
                height: 40
                //just an dummy example to show how to change representation base
                //expression binding
                color: (modelData % 2 === 0) ? "lightGreen" : "red"
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    selected = ! selected;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont really understand how to connect the above code up with a ListView

Comment: The above code show a idea of delegate you may adapt to suit your needs. You just have to provide this delegate to your ListView, provide the proper model, etc..

Comment: Is there any example out there for this? :) Dont really understand